# vpnc “Target networks” and DNSUpdate options not working

Tags: linux, route, vpn

VPNC documentation describes the options to restrict VPN connection route to a range of IPs and also leave system DNS setting untouched.

My vpnc configuration (/etc/conf/default.conf) contains the following lines:

> Target networks 192.168.103.0/24
>   DNSUpdate no

Those work as expected/described above on Ubuntu 9.10, but in certain versions of CentOS and OpenSuSE, running

> $vpnc /etc/conf/default.conf

results in the following:

> vpnc: warning: unknown configuration directive in /etc/vpnc/swisscom.conf at line ##

for both lines mentioned above.

vpnc version is 0.5.3 on all systems.

Did anyone manage to solve this issue?

Thanks
v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a README.Debian file quote:

## UPGRADE NOTES

If you have been using Debian-specific extensions with "Target networks" and
"DNSupdate" directives, consider changing your praxis to use the official
upstream configuration way now. See /usr/share/doc/vpnc/README.gz file for
details about replacing network routes with custom ones using the variables of
vpnc-script. You can either wrap /etc/vpnc/vpnc-script into a custom script
which presets those variables (like documented in the example in README.gz) or
use vpnc-script-connect-action and vpnc-script-disconnect-action scripts to set
them separately (see below), which may or may not be wanted depending on your
setup. Or you can symlink them to have the same config in the both phases.

The same applies to the disabling of DNS data update. The old methods are
preserved with compatibility wrappers for the near future but should be avoided
with new installations.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Didn't go that far :)